# facebook node js logout

Tags: node.js, facebook

using module https://github.com/amachang/facebook-node-sdk
i don't find a method to diconnect from facebook and clear data.

i tried to use `Facebook.prototype.clearAllPersistentData()` but it doesn't work

In other words when i diconnect from facebook and i log in with facebook in my app
the app don't ask me to connect with facebook another time
the problem i still get with the method `loginRequired()` data.
is there a method for logout ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a LoginButton, you can try use: (facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0)

> fbLogin.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY);

insted

> fbLogin.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK); // default

when configuring LoginButton object.